# IMG tag with external SVG file not responsive to scaling of container

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, resize

This is a commonly asked question (and I have looked for, found and tried a variety of other suggestions, here on stackoverflow and elsewhere)

I have an web page where I'd like to dynamically load in maps, which are in SVG format. I would like the maps to be responsive to rescaling of their container, i.e. fill the width of the container as the window resizes for example.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://snacknack.com/1/08.svg" style="height: 1286px;" />
</div>
```

The external 08.svg file starts like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 909 1286">
```

Instead of resizing the SVG remains rock solid at its original size. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pj2RP/2/) *(Note: viewbox edited to viewBox in svg file thanks helderdarocha for spotting that)*

I have tried giving the .container a width:100%, height:100%; but that does not work, nor do various other suggestions for related questions. I am not sure whether that is because I have to use an external file to provide the SVG (rather than doing the SVG inline which is what examples do) or
whether it is because of something inside the SVG content.

I have already tried using an OBJECT tag to bring in the SVG file rather than an IMG tag. Same issue.

If I do not provide the hardcoded height in the IMG tag, the map will truncate at around 377-400px vertically (in my Mac OS Chrome & Safari browsers) and if I set it to height:100% the map disappears entirely.

How do make this IMG tag/SVG responsive ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your fiddle. Your SVG however does not have a `viewBox` attribute (case matters - `viewbox` will not work). If you add one it should scale automatically.

Comment: Ah, did not realize the SVG attribs were case sensitive, thanks for pointing that out. I have changed it to viewBox now, but it still does not rescale properly :(

Comment: You should also remove the fixed height you are applying to it via the `style` attribute.